# Iterate over all selected rows of SSDBGrid to fill an array

Tags: vb6, grid, iteration

I need to iterate over all of the selected rows in an `SSDBGrid`. Then, I need to get the value in the current row and populate the relevant place in the array with this value.

I've been attempting to do this with the code below:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Dim nomCode(Grd_Nominal.SelBookmarks.Count) As String ' This is my array.

Do While Grd_Nominal.SelBookmarks <> 0
   nomCode(i) = Grd_Nominal.SelBookmarks(0)

   If Grd_Nominal.SelBookmarks.Count > 0 Then
       Grd_Nominal.SelBoomarks(0).Remove
   End If

   i = i + 1
Loop
```

However, `nomCode(i)` is always being filled as `nomCode(i) = "??"`

Why is it inserting "??", and how can I fix this to insert the value of the current row?

Comment: ?? might indicate there is some problem related to the character encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first of all re-think how you're declaring your array.

```
Dim nomCode() As String
ReDim nomCode(Grd_Nominal.SelBookmarks.Count - 1) As String
```

This is because when declaring an array you need to pass in a constant as the length. `ReDim` doesn't, so this will go partly towards solving the issue.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim bk As Variant

For x = 0 to Grd_Nominal.Rows.Count - 1
   bm = Grd_Nominal.SelBookmarks(x)
   nomCode(x) = Grd_Nominal.Columns("Your_Column").CellValue(bm)
Next
```

This should sort the rest of the issue, I think.